# How to fit an entire HTML page with min-width and min-height on any screen?

Tags: html, css

I have a page with styles:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  min-width: 1920px;
  min-height: 1080px;
}
```

The page does not fit on a small screen (eg 1280x720) and scrolling appears.
How do I fit a page on any screen in width? That is, I need something to zoom. I tried to use viewport but it only work for mobile screen but not on a PC.

Comment: Have you considered *not* setting a minimum width of 1920px?

Answer (score 1):

```
html, body{
    height:100%;

}
body{
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Does this be not working on pc monitor? BTW it does looks like that it needs for javascript to sum and stretch the size.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1920px){
.container{transform: scale(.8);}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
.container{transform: scale(.6);}
}
```

Comment: This does not work, as `transform` is purely visual and doesn't affect the "reserved" space for the element.

Comment: If the content containing text it'll be so small to even readable. I mainly using mobile browser. Could you tell why that the big dimension preservation of your content is important?

Comment: @Woobie because the customer asked to make the site only for 1920 by 1080 resolution and make "zoom" for the rest of the screens

Comment: Maybe you can get the screen width size, $(window).width(); and then set the container to it. Another math does needed for the height.

Comment: I don't know. It is even unimaginable in real world that you have a smaller screen to contain bigger ones without it goes scrollable. In Russia, just call GRU and your client will be agree for any kind of solution.

Comment: You may try this: https://www.installation-international.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/img_20180322_102553.jpg and this in Redux: https://medium.com/immersion-for-the-win/hands-on-with-virtual-reality-using-a-frame-react-and-redux-bc66240834f7